# Change button color when input fields are filed

Tags: javascript, html

there is one red button with some input fields below button. When inputfields are filled. Button color should change to green.
below this is a second red button. below this second red button are two small red buttons. below small red button are two inputfields.
When inputfields are filled then small red buttons should change to green.
And when both small buttons are green then the bigger button also should change to green.

Tried to create a java script to check if input fields are filled

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Checklist uHTS Webversion</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
button {
  height:40px;
  width:160px;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color:red;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 { background: red }

.button1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.buttonsmall{
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: 4px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color:white;
}
.buttonsmall:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body onload="beginfase()" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;" >
  <p><br><br></p>

<button id = "button" onclick="showOrHide('General')" class="button1" name= "bGeneral" ><b>General</b></button> 

    <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
    <div id="General">
      <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
        <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">        
        </colgroup>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">      
    </td>
    <td width="20%">Protocol name(s) : </td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" id="Protname" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35"> </td>
    <td width="20%"></td>
    <td width="20%"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>      
    </td>
    <td>Order name(s):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>   
  </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
<!-- Create extra space -->
<p><br></p> 

<!-- The Next Button Plates -->
<button id = "buttonP" onclick="showOrHide('Plates')" class="button1" name= "buttonP" ><b>Plates</b></button> 
<!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
 <div id="Plates">
<br>    
<div id="CompoundPlates_button">
 <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
 <colgroup>
    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
    <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"><input type="button" id = "buttonCP"  name="buttonCP" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" >      
    </td>
    <td width="40%"><b>CompoundPlates</></td>
    <td width="15%"></td> 
    <td width="15%"></td>
    <td width="10%"></td>   
  </tr> 
  </table>
 </div> <!-- Close Div CompoundPlates_button --> 
         <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
 <div id="CompoundPlates">
   <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
        <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">        
        </colgroup>
   <tr>
    <td  width="10%">      
    </td>
    <td  width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
    <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="Number of plates" size="35"></td> 
    <td  width="20%"></td>
    <td  width="20%"></td>  
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>      
    </td>
    <td>Order name(s):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>   
  </tr>
   </table>
 </div> <!-- Close div CompoundPlates -->
<div id="AssayPlates_button">
 <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;" >
 <colgroup>
    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
    <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%"><input type="button" id = "buttonAP" name="buttonAP" class="buttonsmall" style="height:20px;width:60px" >      
    </td>
    <td width="40%"><b>AssayPlates</></td>
    <td width="15%"></td> 
    <td width="15%"></td>
    <td width="10%"></td>   
  </tr> 
    </table>
  </div> <!-- Close Div AssayPlates_button -->   
<div id="AssayPlates">
     <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;" >
        <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">        
        </colgroup>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">      
    </td>
    <td width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="Number of platesAP" size="35"></td> 
    <td width="20%"></td>
    <td width="20%"></td>   
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>      
    </td>
    <td>Order name(s):</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>   
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div> <!-- Close div AssayPlates -->
  </div> <!-- Close div Plates -->
<!-- Create extra space -->
<p><br></p> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function allInputsHaveValue (genInputs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < genInputs.length; i++) {
        if (genInputs[i].value.trim() == '') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
var genInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#General input[type="text"]');
for (var i = 0; i < genInputs.length; i++) {
    genInputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        var color = (allInputsHaveValue(genInputs) == true) ? "green" : "red";
        var btn = document.getElementById('button');
        btn.classList.remove("green", "red");
        btn.classList.add(color);
    });
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

expect button color change when input fields are filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update your code with some additional css/javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Checklist uHTS Webversion</title>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        button {
            height: 40px;
            width: 160px;
            border: 4px;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            border-color: red;
            color: yellow;
            padding: 12px 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        /* ADDED CSS */
        button.green,
        input.green {
            background: green;
        }
        /* ADDED CSS -- end*/

        .button1 {
            background: red
        }

        .button1:hover {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .buttonsmall {
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border: 4px;
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            border-color: white;
        }

        .buttonsmall:hover {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="beginfase()" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
    <p><br><br></p>

    <button id="button" onclick="showOrHide('General')" class="button1" name="bGeneral"><b>General</b></button>

    <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
    <div id="General">
        <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
            <colgroup>
                <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                </td>
                <td width="20%">Protocol name(s) : </td>
                <td width="30%"><input type="text" id="Protname" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35"> </td>
                <td width="20%"></td>
                <td width="20%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>Order name(s):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br></p>

    <!-- The Next Button Plates -->
    <button id="buttonP" onclick="showOrHide('Plates')" class="button1" name="buttonP"><b>Plates</b></button>
    <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
    <div id="Plates">
        <br>
        <div id="CompoundPlates_button">
            <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
                <colgroup>
                    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
                    <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="buttonCP" name="buttonCP" class="buttonsmall"
                            style="height:20px;width:60px">
                    </td>
                    <td width="40%"><b>CompoundPlates</>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%"></td>
                    <td width="15%"></td>
                    <td width="10%"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- Close Div CompoundPlates_button -->
        <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
        <div id="CompoundPlates">
            <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
                <colgroup>
                    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
                    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="Number of plates" size="35"></td>
                    <td width="20%"></td>
                    <td width="20%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>Order name(s):</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- Close div CompoundPlates -->
        <div id="AssayPlates_button">
            <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
                <colgroup>
                    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
                    <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="buttonAP" name="buttonAP" class="buttonsmall"
                            style="height:20px;width:60px">
                    </td>
                    <td width="40%"><b>AssayPlates</>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%"></td>
                    <td width="15%"></td>
                    <td width="10%"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- Close Div AssayPlates_button -->
        <div id="AssayPlates">
            <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
                <colgroup>
                    <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
                    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="Number of platesAP" size="35"></td>
                    <td width="20%"></td>
                    <td width="20%"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>Order name(s):</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Order name(s)" size="35"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- Close div AssayPlates -->
    </div> <!-- Close div Plates -->
    <!-- Create extra space -->
    <p><br></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function allInputsHaveValue(genInputs) {
            for (var i = 0; i < genInputs.length; i++) {
                if (genInputs[i].value.trim() == '') return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        var genInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#General input[type="text"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < genInputs.length; i++) {
            genInputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
                var color = (allInputsHaveValue(genInputs) == true) ? "green" : "red";

                var btn = document.getElementById('button');
                btn.classList.remove("green", "red");
                btn.classList.add(color);
            });
        }



        /* ADDED JAVASCRIPT */
        function check_CompoundAndAssyButtons() {
            var btnCP = document.getElementById('buttonCP');
            var btnAP = document.getElementById('buttonAP');

            var color = ((btnCP.classList.contains('green')) && (btnAP.classList.contains('green'))) ? "green" : "red";

            var btn = document.getElementById('buttonP');
            btn.classList.remove("green", "red");
            btn.classList.add(color);
        }

        var CompoundPlatesInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#CompoundPlates input[type="text"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < CompoundPlatesInputs.length; i++) {
            CompoundPlatesInputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
                var color = (allInputsHaveValue(CompoundPlatesInputs) == true) ? "green" : "red";
                var btn = document.getElementById('buttonCP');
                btn.classList.remove("green", "red");
                btn.classList.add(color);

                check_CompoundAndAssyButtons();
            });
        }

        var assyPlatesInput = document.querySelectorAll('#AssayPlates input[type="text"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < assyPlatesInput.length; i++) {
            assyPlatesInput[i].addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
                var color = (allInputsHaveValue(assyPlatesInput) == true) ? "green" : "red";
                var btn = document.getElementById('buttonAP');
                btn.classList.remove("green", "red");
                btn.classList.add(color);

                check_CompoundAndAssyButtons();
            });
        }
        /* ADDED JAVASCRIPT -- end */
        // JSFIDDLE
        // https://jsfiddle.net/tk6430p7/5/
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow this does exactly what i tried. Thanks a lot. Now I can continue with the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this. using this you can see that how can we change the color of button when the input fields are fill.
use **#idForm:valid .button** for button if fields are fill

```
        .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        text-align: center;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F4F6F9, #D3D8E8);
         font-family: Arial;
     }

     #idForm:valid .button {
      background : yellow;
     }

    <div class="wrapper">
        <main class="main">
            <h2>Form</h2>
            <form id="idForm" method="GET" action="action.html">
                <label for="uName"><b>uName:</b></label>
                <input id="uName" type="text" placeholder="uName" required/><br/>
                <label for="pswrd"><b>pswrd:</b></label>
                <input id="pswrd" type="pswrd" placeholder="pswrd" required/><br/>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Form"/><br/>
            </form>
        </main>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the value of the elements by their id and check if they are empty. In addition, put the check in a method that is called with the onkeyup method so that every time a change is made in any of the input, the check is made.
In this example, when you fill in all the fields, the Plates button turns green. If you empty one, it is red again.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <title>Checklist uHTS Webversion</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    button {
      height: 40px;
      width: 160px;
      border: 4px;
      border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
      border-color: red;
      color: yellow;
      padding: 12px 15px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button1 {
      background: red
    }

    .button1:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .buttonsmall {
      background-color: #FF0000;
      border: 4px;
      border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
      border-color: white;
    }

    .buttonsmall:hover {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
  <p><br><br></p>

  <button id="button" onclick="showOrHide('General')" class="button1" name="bGeneral"><b>General</b></button>

  <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
  <div id="General">
    <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td width="10%">
        </td>
        <td width="20%">Protocol name(s) : </td>
        <td width="30%"><input type="text" id="Protname" name="Protocol name(s)" size="35" onkeyup="changeColor()">
        </td>
        <td width="20%"></td>
        <td width="20%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>Order name(s):</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Order" name="Order name(s)" size="35" onkeyup="changeColor()"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br></p>

  <!-- The Next Button Plates -->
  <button id="buttonP" onclick="showOrHide('Plates')" class="button1" name="buttonP"><b>Plates</b></button>
  <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
  <div id="Plates">
    <br>
    <div id="CompoundPlates_button">
      <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
        <colgroup>
          <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
          <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="buttonCP" name="buttonCP" class="buttonsmall"
              style="height:20px;width:60px">
          </td>
          <td width="40%"><b>CompoundPlates</>
          </td>
          <td width="15%"></td>
          <td width="15%"></td>
          <td width="10%"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div> <!-- Close Div CompoundPlates_button -->
    <!-- Insert a table in a div, so this can be hide -->
    <div id="CompoundPlates">
      <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
        <colgroup>
          <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%">
          </td>
          <td width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
          <td width="30%"><input type="text" id="Number1" name="Number of plates" size="35" onkeyup="changeColor()">
          </td>
          <td width="20%"></td>
          <td width="20%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>Order name(s):</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="Order1" name="Order name(s)" size="35" onkeyup="changeColor()"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div> <!-- Close div CompoundPlates -->
    <div id="AssayPlates_button">
      <table style="width:20%;margin-left:50px;">
        <colgroup>
          <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
          <!--<col style="background-color:yellow"> -->
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><input type="button" id="buttonAP" name="buttonAP" class="buttonsmall"
              style="height:20px;width:60px">
          </td>
          <td width="40%"><b>AssayPlates</>
          </td>
          <td width="15%"></td>
          <td width="15%"></td>
          <td width="10%"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div> <!-- Close Div AssayPlates_button -->
    <div id="AssayPlates">
      <table style="width:50%;margin-left:50px;">
        <colgroup>
          <col span="3" style="background-color:#E3CEF6;">
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%">
          </td>
          <td width="20%">Number of Plates:</td>
          <td width="30%"><input type="text" id="Number2" name="Number of platesAP" size="35" onkeyup="changeColor()">
          </td>
          <td width="20%"></td>
          <td width="20%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>Order name(s):</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="Order2" name="Order name(s)" size="35" onkeyup="changeColor()"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div> <!-- Close div AssayPlates -->
  </div> <!-- Close div Plates -->
  <!-- Create extra space -->
  <p><br></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor() {
        var miElemento = $('#Protname').val();
        var miElemento2 = $('#Order').val();
        var miElemento3 = $('#Number1').val();
        var miElemento4 = $('#Order1').val();
        var miElemento5 = $('#Number2').val();
        var miElemento6 = $('#Order2').val();
        if (miElemento !== "" && miElemento2 !== "" && miElemento3 !== "" && miElemento4 !== "" && miElemento5 !==
          "" && miElemento6 !== "") {
          $("#buttonP").css("background-color", "green");
        } else {
          $("#buttonP").css("background-color", "red");
        }
      }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```